# Tensorfow 2.11.0: Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am following the instruction here:https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip I was able to follow the instruction step by step without any problems, but TF doesn't detect GPUs.

tensorflow2.11.0 and python: 3.7.10

[image]

```
2023-02-28 01:02:51.625308: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-02-28 01:02:51.753482: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:104] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-02-28 01:02:53.042228: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/compat:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/compat:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/home/gesong/.conda/envs/tf/lib/:/home/gesong/.conda/envs/tf/lib/
2023-02-28 01:02:53.042457: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/compat:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/compat:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/home/gesong/.conda/envs/tf/lib/:/home/gesong/.conda/envs/tf/lib/
2023-02-28 01:02:53.042475: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2023-02-28 01:02:54.601061: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/compat:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/compat:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/home/gesong/.conda/envs/tf/lib/:/home/gesong/.conda/envs/tf/lib/
2023-02-28 01:02:54.602005: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Which system OS are you using to get GPU support? Because if you are using Win OS then `TensorFlow 2.11` will not be a compatible version to enable GPU.

Please check the below mentioned comment in your given [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally,
> try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

or you can install `TensorFlow version 2.10` or lesser than that and follow the [step by step instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) mentioned in the link to have GPU support enabled in your system.